# Create this type of array

Tags: arrays, reactjs

This is what I want:

```
[
    { value: '1', label: 'LABEL 1' },
    { value: '2', label: 'LABEL 2' },
    { value: '3', label: 'LABEL 3' },
    { value: '4', label: 'LABEL 4' },
]
```

Currently I have this, but seems not working. The namesToSearch return an array of names.

```
const increment = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
const RequiredData = [{
   value: increment,
   label: namesToSearch,
}]
            
this.setState({ namesToSearch: RequiredData })
```

This output something like:

```
[…]
0: {…}
label: (3) […]
0: "label 1"
1: "label 2"
2: "label 3"
value: (4) […]
0: "1"
1: "2"
2: "3"
3: "4"
```

Comment: You need to use `Array.map` to get the result.

Comment: Is namesToSearch another array that you want to combine with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
const increment = ['1', '2', '3', '4'];
const RequiredData = increment.map((value, index) => ({
  value,
  label: namesToSearch[index],
}));

this.setState({ namesToSearch: RequiredData });
```

Comment: Thats nice!! How can I make increment flexible and without forcing 4 values?

Comment: `const increment = Array.from({ length: 100 }).map((_, index) => index + '');` Make sure namesToSearch is the same length or do  `const increment = Array.from({ length: namesToSearch.length }).map((_, index) => index + '');`